# A Grave Accent?

Tags: differences, punctuation

`' ‘`

See the two characters above. I've placed the single-quote there for contrast. Out of curiosity what is the first character called?  It seems to give me a lot of trouble in my software.  Is it called a Grave Accent?  Either way when should it be used?

Answer (score 1):

The first character (`'`) is an [*apostrophe*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe), the second character (`‘`) is an [*acute accent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent).

Reversed acute accent is called [*grave accent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent).

Comment: The first is indeed an apostrophe, but the second character is a single quote. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark

Comment: Just copy any character and paste it into the Wikipedia search box and it will tell you what it is.